# User close the app while the account firebase is creating the account Android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I have a simple app that people can sign up (register).
After that I do two things:

1) I send the verification email;

2) I create the firebase database information for this user.

I create two nodes as you can see in the picture.

**"users" node**

[image: "users" node]

**"users_settings" node**

[image: "users_settings" node]

And there are two problems:

1) It seems that 1 in each 20 accounts get an error when creating and this special account does not create the "users_settings" node, it just created the "users" node and only with the full_name field. Like this one in this picture.

[image: "users" node with error]

**there is no "users_settings" node**

I asked the two users who got this problem and did not find anything they did wrong and I created multiple accounts and did not get this error. That's why it is a kind hard to solve this.

2)If the user press the register button and close the app while it is loading, firebase create the account, send the verification email, but does not create any firebase database information because it does not get into this part of the code. Is there a way to prevent this from happening?

This is the code when the person press the register button, it just take the fields (name, emial, password) and register in firebase.

**RegisterFragment.java**

```
    /**
 * When the user press the REGISTER BUTTON.
 */
private void init(){
    Log.i(TAG, "init: Initializing the button click");

    mRegisterButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            String email = mEmail.getText().toString();
            String fullName = mFullName.getText().toString();
            String password = mPassword.getText().toString();

            if (stringIsNull(email) || stringIsNull(fullName) || stringIsNull(password)){
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), R.string.fillin_all_fields, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {

                firebaseMethods = new FirebaseMethods(getActivity());

                /*
                 * 1) Create an intent to the same Login Screen;
                 * 2) Register email (Send verification email, if OK start Login Screen again and send message to verify the email).
                 */
                Intent intentLogin = new Intent(getActivity(), LoginActivity.class);

                firebaseMethods.registerNewEmail(email, password, fullName, mProgressBar, intentLogin);

            }

        }
    });

}
```

This is my **registerNewEmail** Firebase method:

**FirebaseMethods.java**

```
/**
 * Register a new user to the Firebase Authentication with his email and password.
 * @param email the user's email for registering
 * @param password the user's password for registering
 */
public void registerNewEmail(String email, String password, final String fullName, final ProgressBar progressBar, final Intent intent){

    progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
            .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                        // Sign in success, update UI with the signed-in user's information
                        Log.i(TAG, "createUserWithEmail:success");
                        final FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();

                        if (user != null){

                            user.sendEmailVerification()
                                    .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                                            if (task.isSuccessful()){
                                                Log.i(TAG, "onComplete: Successful send verification email");
                                                Toast.makeText(mContext, mContext.getString(R.string.confirm_email_verification)
                                                        + user.getEmail(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                                                // 1) Add user's info to database;
                                                // 2) Sign out to wait for the email verification;
                                                // 3) Go to login activity.
                                                addNewUser(fullName, "", "", "", "", "", false);

                                                mContext.startActivity(intent);

                                            } else {
                                                Log.i(TAG, "onComplete: Failed to send verification email");
                                                Toast.makeText(mContext, mContext.getString(R.string.failed_send_verification_email),
                                                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                            }
                                        }
                                    });

                        }

                        /*updateUI(user);*/
                    } else {
                        // If sign in fails, display a message to the user.
                        Log.i(TAG, "createUserWithEmail:failure", task.getException());
                        if (task.getException() != null) {
                            Toast.makeText(mContext, "Authentication failed." + task.getException().getMessage(),
                                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                        /*updateUI(null);*/
                    }

                    progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
            });

}
```

This is my **addNewUser** method:

**FirebaseMethods.java**

```
    private void addNewUser(String fullName, String birthDate, String beltColor, String registrationNumber, String dojo, String profileImgURL, boolean verified) {

    FirebaseUser currentUser = mAuth.getCurrentUser();

    if (currentUser != null) {

        String userID = currentUser.getUid();

        Log.i(TAG, "addNewUser: Adding new user database information: " + userID);


        // Creating the user model with the information provided.
        User user = new User(
                dojo,
                fullName,
                profileImgURL,
                registrationNumber,
                verified);

        // Adding to the database;
        myRef.child(mContext.getString(R.string.dbname_users))
                .child(userID)
                .setValue(user);

        // Creating the user_settings model with the information provided.
        UserSettings user_settings = new UserSettings(
                beltColor,
                birthDate,
                userID);

        // Adding to the database
        myRef.child(mContext.getString(R.string.dbname_users_settings))
                .child(userID)
                .setValue(user_settings);

        // 1) Added the information for the user that just registered;
        // 2) Sign out to wait for email verification.
        mAuth.signOut();

    }

}
```

You can see I create the complete model User (dojo, fullName, profileImgURL, registrationNumber, verified) and the complete model UserSettings (beltColor, birthDate, userID).

And I add it to the firebase at once, so I can not see a way it is adding only the full name field and it is not adding the UserSettings.

Help me please! This is my first app released.

Comment: do you have a `user_settings` class? you should have smth like `childUpdates.put("/user-settings/" + userId + "/" + key, settingsValue);`

Comment: why dont you add `beltColor, birthDate` directly to the user class?

Comment: I havve the UserSettings class (model), I divided into two nodes because there are many times in the app I call just the information in "users" node so I did not want to call too many information.

Comment: What is the difference of using push() or just using setValue() as I did? I'll try but it'll take a time to see if it worked because it does not happen everytime. But'll let u know. Thank you!

Comment: OK try this one `mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
String userId = user.getUid();
Firebase rootRef = new Firebase(Config.USER_URL);
Firebase userRef = rootRef.child("Users");
UserSettings  newS = new UserSettings ();
newS.setFirstName(firstName);
userRef.child(userId).setValue(user_settings);`